# App builds but does not open on android device

Tags: android, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to run my react native app on an android phone. It builds successfully but only opens for 2 seconds on the phone and then crashes with a notification that 'appname has stopped'.

What could be the possibilities? I have tried basic things like:

```
npm watchman watch-del-all
m -rf node_modules and run yarn install
yarn start --reset-cache
```

The app works fine on ios Simulator but not on an adroid device. It was working last time though.

Comment: adb logs will help you ... explore how to show add logs for react native.

Answer (score 0):

@Jnl try to clean entire cache.. ie: **gradlew cache** also.

> For windows:  Please use this `del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Are you facing this problem in  debug mode or generated apk ?